# Bootstrap Slider capabilities

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new in Bootstrap and now i'm checking it's sliders capabilities.
Simple sliders and animation effects - all is ok.

But I can't understand, can I make something like this? -http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/basic.html

Waiting for answers and ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be talking about [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), the popular CSS library.  If you like the owl-carousel demo, it wouldn't be a bad idea to simply integrate theirs!

If you want to do it by hand, you could show/hide certain images based on how you press the buttons.  This could be done with jQuery.  That said, most people recommend [moving away from sliders](http://searchengineland.com/homepage-sliders-are-bad-for-seo-usability-163496) in general!